# Google PubSub Emulator: How to configure logging level

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

What logging framework does Google PubSub Emulator use and how could I configure it?

At the moment it is quite verbose, I would like to silence it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google PubSub Emulator uses java.util.logging.

To silence the verbose output one needs to manually provide logging.properties to the jar executable:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/logging.properties
```